# Grails domain class transient collection attribute setter issue

Tags: grails, collections, grails-orm, getter-setter, transient

I am trying to set (or bind) value to a transient List attribute. But I failed with collections.
On the other hand transient String attribute working well on setter.

Grails version 2.4.3

Any advice?

```
@Resource(uri = "/api/samples", formats = ["json"])
class Sample {

    static transients = ["fields","sample"]

    String regions
    String name
    String sample


    List<String> fields

    List<String> getFields() {
        this.regions != null ? Arrays.asList(regions.split("\\s*,\\s*")) : new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    void setFields(List<String> fields) {
        if (fields != null && !fields.isEmpty()) {
            this.regions = fields.join(",")
        }
    }

    void setSample(String sample){
        this.name = sample
    }

    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untyped fields are transient by default, so this alternative approach should work (and is a lot more concise):

```
@Resource(uri = "/api/samples", formats = ["json"])
class Sample {

    static transients = ["sample"]

    String regions
    String name
    String sample


    def getFields() {
        this.regions != null ? Arrays.asList(regions.split("\\s*,\\s*")) : []
    }

    void setFields(def fieldList) {
        if (fieldList) {
            this.regions = fieldList.join(",")
        }
    }

    void setSample(String sample){
        this.name = sample
    }

    static mapping = {
    }
}
```